# RAM usage discrepancy? Memory leak? Ubuntu 18.10 with Cinnamon

Tags: ram

So I'm fairly new to using Ubuntu, but what I've been finding is that I need to reboot regularly because eventually (over the course of a day or two) I seem to run out of usable RAM and stop being able to play the games I play because they lock up and start disk thrashing and if I'm lucky I'll be able to wait it out and force-close the game, and if I'm not I'll need to just hard-reboot. The weirdest thing about it, though is this:

[image: 1]

This shows that just about half my RAM is in use. But then I tab over to the processes page and:

[image: 2]

As you can see, this is without even running things like a browser or anything. So where has the RAM gone?

Comment: Please include the output of typing `free -m` in a terminal into your question.

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

re: "*I seem to run out of usable RAM and stop being able to play the games I play because they lock up and start disk thrashing*"

Even on normally running computers, it'll look like RAM is fully used, as any free RAM is used for disk/file buffers.

One key to solving system lockups is tuning RAM vs swap and tuning a parameter vm.swappiness. You have enough RAM. Your swap is probably too small, and we may need to make it larger. And vm.swappiness is default at 60.

Without enlarging your swap, try temporarily setting vm.swappiness like so...

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=80
```

If that improves things, come back here and I'll show you how to make that setting permanent.